# Cannot create a new table in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a new table in firebase without succes. I am already added the app to firebase downloaded the `google-services.json` and synced gradle files.

Now i am tring to add new table via code :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

But "Users" table is not added to the db. I change the rules of write and read to be "true" and still the table is not created.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you shared doesn't create anything in Firebase yet.

Try setting a value and you'll see the path being created. E.g. `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").setValue(true)`